# How to fix extra quotes in CSV files?

Tags: csv

I receive data feeds in the form of CSV files that are sometimes invalid due to extra quotes. For example:

```
110253,TDE,"Telefonica 0253",LSE,1,2014-05-21,2014-11-28,,,2,,,493900,Ordinary Share
110254,TRCN,"OJSC "Transcontainer",LSE,1,2014-05-21,2014-11-28,,,2,,,0,
110255,TTA,"Total SA 110255",LSE,1,2014-05-21,2014-11-28,,,2,,,369200,Ordinary Share
```

On the second line, notice the extra double-quote that should be escaped but isn't.

There is no way for me to fix the original data or the feed. Is there a good tool that I can use to try to fix the data itself after I receive it?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot vouch for its quality, but here you go: https://code.google.com/p/csvfix/